# Numbers: Can you write text to a cell with a formula?

Tags: numbers

I want to do a conditional check in a cell and write text to a separate cell on the results.

So, in F1, I would have this formula:

```
IF((A2)=(A1),(G1)="duplicate", (G1)="")
```

but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula does not work because you can’t have a cell directly modify another cell in Numbers. For it to work, you should revise your formula as follows and put it in G1 itself:

```
IF(A2=A1,"duplicate","")
```

I have removed some of the parentheses as well because they are unnecessary in this case.